# SqlDataAdapter, SqlBulkCopy and DataTable with NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to use `SqlBulkCopy` with .net core, but since I use a geometry column the following code requires Microsoft.SqlServer.Types which is not fully .net core compatible, especially on Linux.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM " + tableName, sqlConnection))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Without the dependency the `Fill()` fails as it cannot find the type.

Normally I use NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes, but in this case the magic happens somewhere in the SqlDataAdapter and I don't know how to overwrite it.

I tried to create the DataTable columns manually without using `Fill()`, but it seems whatever type I specify I later get an error in the SqlBulkCopy.

> The given value of type XYZ from the data source cannot be converted to type udt of the specified target column

I tried with `SqlBytes` and `byte[]`, but nothing seems to work.

**Update 1:**
I got it working with a manually created DataTable with `byte[]` as the type for that column.

Still it would be nice to have a way using `adapter.Fill(dt);` or similar so that I do not have to manually list all the columns.

Comment: // Create the Table
DataTable OrdersTable = new DataTable("Orders");
// Build the Orders schema
ordersTable.Columns.Add("ID" Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
ordersTable.Columns.Add("Name" Type.GetType("System.String"));
ordersTable.Columns.Add("Amount" Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

foreach(var r in td.Rows)
{
DataRow dr = OrdersTable.NewRow();

dr[0] = r[0] // the columns should secuencial for two tables
.
.

ordersTable.rows.add(dr);
}

Comment: @LDS, with a manually created DataTable it works, however I was hoping for a way that does not require coding all the columns. The beauty of the version with Fill() is that it takes all the types from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM " + tableName, sqlConnection)
    
    {
        using (SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da))
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dt = dgPurchase.DataSource as DataTable;
            //here assign the data table
                da.Fill(dataSet, dt);
            
            da.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand(true);

            //da.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand(true);
            //If new row then open it
                    da.Update(dataSet, dt);

        }
     }

 // Can update though parameters .Follow the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters

//Useing inline code .Follow the link
http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/updatecommand-sqlserver.htm
```